# Conditional rendering just for the if condition, not the else

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code:
I basically want to render this input in case the `checkedRadio` state is equals to 'Yes'. I don't think the conditional render is used well in this situation. In case `checkedRadio` is not 'Yes', I want it to render nothing.

```
           {checkedRadio === "Yes" ? (
              <input
                className="registerGitHubInput"
                type="text"
                placeholder="GitHub Username"
                value={githubUsername.githubUsername}
                onChange={(e) => setGithubUsername(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            ) : (
              <></> // <-- Is this correct?
            )}
```

At least the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify using the `&&` operator. See https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator.

```
{checkedRadio === "Yes" && 
  <input
    className="registerGitHubInput"
    type="text"
    placeholder="GitHub Username"
    value={githubUsername.githubUsername}
    onChange={(e) => setGithubUsername(e.target.value)}
    required
  />
}
```